# How to sort an array of optional values?

Tags: sorting, rust

I have an array of optional values

```
struct Foo;

let array: [Option<Foo>; 5] = [
    Some(Foo {}), 
    Some(Foo {}), 
    None, 
    Some(Foo {}), 
    None
];
```

How to sort the array to "bubble" all `None` values to the top (left/ascending)?

The expected result should look like this

```
println!("{:?}", array) // [None, None, Some(Foo {}), Some(Foo {}), Some(Foo {})]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`None` is compared as less than `Some`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/index.html#comparison-operators), so assuming `Foo` implements `Ord`, you just need to call [`sort_unstable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable) (or [`sort()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) for stable sorting).

If you *only* want to bubble `None`s (and not compare the values of `Some`s), you can use `sort[_unstable]_by_key(|v| v.is_some())`. Since `false` compares before `true`, this will place the `None`s first.

Comment: Thanks, `sort_by_key(|v| v.is_some())` is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: It's worth noting that sorting is `O(n log(n))`. When you simply have 2 categories of elements and you want one after the other, it is better (`O(n)`) to [partition the slice](https://github.com/llogiq/partition). This is unlikely to matter in all but the most extreme cases though.

Comment: @ReinisMazeiks Yeah, I just wanted to add that...